# 19.04 Disco Dingo linux-image-5.0.0-13-lowlatency Failed

Tags: upgrade

After downloading everything and going through the upgrade process from 18.10 to 19.04 using the onscreen prompts, there was an error that ***linux-image-5.0.0-13-lowlatency*** could not be installed. After that, the installation closed with an error that the system might not be unusable. I am on it at the moment but have not yet rebooted for fear that it won't come back up. What should I do to finalize the installation?

```
sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.

sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  calf-plugins
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

Interestingly and in spite the error, it appears that the kernel did install after all. Perhaps the error was, well, in error, as the system seems to be fine:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-5.0.0-13-lowlatency
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
linux-image-5.0.0-13-lowlatency is already the newest version (5.0.0-13.14).
linux-image-5.0.0-13-lowlatency set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install -f`, and add the output to the question, in case there are still errors.

Comment: Not sure what output to post as the upgrade was done through the the GUI but I did add the output from sudo apt-get install -f

Comment: So try `sudo apt-get upgrade`, and post the output again.

Comment: Added the output!

Comment: Well, that has nothing to do with the kernel, as far as I can tell. There are no broken packages, so nothing to fix or finalize. You can check which kernels are installed with `dplg -l | grep linux-image`, and install more if something is amiss.

Comment: Try running `sudo apt-get install linux-image-5.0.0-13-lowlatency` again and see what you get.  Include whatever output you get as an edit here.

Comment: @mikewhatever I do believe you meant `dpkg -l | grep linux-image` :)

Comment: I added the output for sudo apt-get install linux-image-5.0.0-13-lowlatency which installed nothing so apparently the original error was bogus and possibly a bug of some sort. Since I rarely have upgrades go smoothly, it had me worried.

Comment: @DonP Yeah the warning you got was a different issue - that there's a package that was kept back because it has additional dependencies you have to approve.  I don't see an actual issue here with the kernel install.